# how to set gravity in button which it's background is drawable?

Tags: android, android-button

i have a button which i set it's background as followed:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
```

after that i added text to the button and i wanted it to be centered:

```
button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

but it doesn't work.

the drawable is shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-1dp" android:right="-1dp">
      <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
      </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

how do i set gravity to the button?

Comment: what output your are getting show us some screenshot what you need and what is happening when you are trying mentioned code?

Comment: You create button dynamically?

Comment: Yes, i created the button dynamically. I can't upload the screenshot right now, but i can tell that the text is in the top of the button, instead in the middle.

Comment: make a LinearLayout and set that layout gravity to Center to make your button to be situated in the center

Answer (score 1):

In your XML file of layout put one button.

code for xml is below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="Button" />
```

Now in your activity

For set gravity of button Do this..

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button b;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

        b.setLayoutParams(params);



}
```

}

This will work for me....

Happy coding....